# Is there an eval in ruby

Tags: python, ruby

Does ruby have something like pythons eval? I'm searching google and I don't know if it's how i'm searching but I can't find anything on it or how to use it if there is one

In python I would something like this

```
def doEval(object):
    return repr(eval(object))
```

The code above you would do in python's idle or something and run doEval('print("hello")') it would print "hello" then return "None" to say it was executed, in ruby I don't mind if it doesn't do nil, but I would like it to eval

Anything like this in ruby? thanks.

Comment: Yes `eval` is present in Ruby too... Don't understand what you are trying to do,....

Comment: There is `eval` in ruby but if you explain what does the above code do in python I may be able to provide more detailed answer.

Comment: How does that action differ from simply executing the function?

Comment: It exists, but is as evil as eval is in python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Googling "ruby eval" quickly reveals that the answer is yes.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)

> eval(string [, binding [, filename [,lineno]]]) → obj
>
> Evaluates the Ruby expression(s) in *string*. If *binding* is given, which
>   must be a `Binding` object, the evaluation is performed in its context.
>   If the optional *filename* and *lineno* parameters are present, they will
>   be used when reporting syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
command = "puts 1"
eval(command)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

Comment: works, thank you I can not believe it's the exact same though feeling idiotic but thanks